# Java - Sockets and Swing

Tags: java, swing, sockets, client-server

I'm still learning swing and sockets both, so bear with me. To learn I'm making a chat client/server system. Right now, I'm working on the client. My classes are

- **Main** (With the main method) [code link](http://pastebin.com/PPBJKXj9)
- **Window** (Sets up Swing components) [code link](http://pastebin.com/E4J0qrGU)
- **ActLis**(Handles all component action listeners from Window) [code link](http://pastebin.com/grz7b7vV)
- **SocketManager**(Manages my sockets) [code link](http://pastebin.com/7jdQzBbq)

I set up a `SocketManager` object in `Main` when the program runs, but then when `ActLis` needs to use that socket to `send a message` I don't know of a good way to get it from `Main`. Is what I'm doing completely ineffective and there is a better way to set it up, or is there a way to get my `SocketManager` object from my `Main` class that I don't know? *(I realize there are other problems in my code, but I'm just trying to get sockets to work for a start, I'm having a hard time with them.)*

Comment: Just pass the `SocketManager` object to your `ActLis` class

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Yes, but how would I do that? Every time I try I get a null pointer, because I need to create a **Main** object in **ActLis** to access **Main**'s **SocketManager** object. The **Main** object I create though is not the same one the **SocketManager** object had been set up in so it's null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

> 1) Have a ActLis object in the Main class and pass Main's reference to SocketManager to it

```
public class Main
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       ActList        a = new ActList(...);
       SocketManager sm = new SocketManager(...);

       a.sendMessageWithSocket(sm); //here you pass Main's reference to SocketManager 
   }                                //object to the ActLis class for use
}
```

> 2) Let the ActLis class have a reference to the SocketManager object, set in its constructor

```
public class ActLis
{
    private SocketManager sm;

    public ActLis(SocketManager sm)
    {
        this.sm = sm;
    }
}
```

These are probably the most simple ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

adding to Hunter McMillen's:

> 3) Make Main class, singleton. id est do not let more than one instance of it (If I've had understood your purpose, you don't need more than one instance of this class.) so just make a single instance of this class and keep its reference as a public static final field in it. (and of course don't let it be instantiated from outside this class:

```
    public class Main
    {
        public static final Main instance = new Main(/*args*/);

        private Main(/*args*/)
        {
            //blah blah
        }
    }
```

This way you can access your `Socket` field in `Main` form anywhere in your code with no problem.